# Magento, login as customer from admin

Tags: php, session, magento, authentication

I've extended the `Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController` with a new action `loginAction` in order to be able to login as a customer from the admin interface.

I call the `loginById` on the `customer/session`, but the customer's session isn't modified after the redirect.

Can someone explain why? It should be a simple operation.

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/1216073) containing the `loginAction`

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

---

#### Update:

I created a github-repo containing all the code for the module: https://github.com/KATT/Magento-CustomerLogin.

Once this issue is solved, it might be useful for someone else as well.

Comment: An hint that could prevent headaches: you can't set the Customer Session within ad Admin controller, it won't be stored, so you are obliged to call authenticate from a Frontend controller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi I created a way to login as a customer. With the following solution below you can get an action in the customer grid management view in backend for each customer:

You have to create a controller for the frontend and do a class rewrite of an admin block, please adapt to your situation and don't forget to create a xml file which activate your module at app/etc/modules/Yourmodule_Customer.xml
Here is the config.xml of a module that you will have to create:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Yourmodule_Customer>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Yourmodule_Customer>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
      <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
          <customer_grid>Yourmodule_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Overwrite_Grid</customer_grid>
         </rewrite>
       </adminhtml>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <customer before="Mage_Customer">Yourmodule_Customer_Overwrite</customer>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Then you have to create a block class in the folder Youmodule/Customer/Block/Adminhtml/Overwrite/Grid.php with the following content:
Be aware that if you have Store Code in URL activated, you need here to provide a default store code.

```
<?php
class Yourmodule_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Overwrite_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $column = $this->getColumn('action');
        $actions = $column->getActions();
        $actions[] = array(
            'caption' => 'Log in',
            'popup' => true,
            'url' => array(
                'base' => 'customer/support/autologin',
                'params' => array('_store' => 'de', '_secure' => true)),
                'field' => 'customerid'
        );
        $column->setActions( $actions );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then you have to create a new frontend controller, in this case, it's restricted to authorized IP address defined in the backend configuration:

```
<?php
class Yourmodule_Customer_Overwrite_SupportController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function preDispatch(){

        parent::preDispatch();

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
            return;
        }

        $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
        $pattern = '/^(autologin)/i';
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $action) && Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())) {
            if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
                $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
            }
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
        }
    }

    public function autologinAction(){
        $session = $this->_getSession();

        $id = (int) trim($this->getRequest()->getParam('customerid'));
        try{
            if($id){
                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
                $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                $message = $this->__('You are now logged in as %s', $customer->getName());
                $session->addNotice($message);
                Mage::log($message);
            }else{
                throw new Exception ($this->__('Auto Loggin didn\'t worked. Some parameter are missing'));
            }
        }catch (Exception $e){
            $session->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        $this->_redirect('customer/account');       
    }

    public function _getSession(){
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet. +1. I just changed the conditions so that instead of that `isDevAllowed`, I checked if the user is an admin through `Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()`. That should be safe usage, right?

I still can't understand why I can't change the customer-session from the admin-side though. But this is a pretty good workaround.

Comment: @AlexanderJohansson: yes, you are right about the `isLoggedIn()` tested from the admin session. It's a good idea too. About your controller problem, maybe you should check:
- Test if `$session->loginById($customerID);` returns true or false in your controller. If false, the customer id doesn't exist or a problem occured while loading the customer model.
- Test the same controller in a frontend context and not in a Adminhtml context. Replace `Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController` by `Mage_Customer_AccountController` for example. I didn't test it.

Comment: @AlexanderJohansson @KennyD: KennyD provide an important point in your problem. The Website ID. Your problem could come from this missing `$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());` that the reason I told you to put your controller in a frontend context. In Admin, the webiste ID is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question has already been answered, but for those looking for somewhat different (not saying better) approach, here is the Magento extension I wrote https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_LoginAsCustomer. It does not rewrite any blocks, it uses event/observer to inject Login as Customer button on the customer edit screen. It further uses combination of admin and frontend controller to pass the encrypted customer info around so it knows which customer to login.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you supossed to login via the customer model?

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
OR
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
```

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());` is kindof exactly what I'm doing. I get the customer's ID from the request.

Answer (score 0):

For those who does not want to debug the solution you can install the extension via magento connect:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-as-customer-9893.html
It allows to login from customer view and order view pages from admin. The extension is stable and works fine in all cases