# Magento: Login to frontend with admin credentials

Tags: magento

Is there any way provided by Magento to login to frontend with admin credentials. I
I've tried many tutorials and forums but in vain.

Is there any extension available for this? Can we achieve this by custom coding? If yes, How?

Comment: what's the point, create a frontend user instead?

Comment: I've suggested that to client, But he want the same credentials for frontend.

Comment: there is no built in way, since Magento has separate sessions for frontend and admin part (for security reasons). As Anton mentioned, don't see any point in doing what you want

Comment: As an alternate to this, As suggested by Anton, I can create frontend user with same admin credentials, Then can I login to magento frontend with username instead of email?

Comment: please explain what is your goal so others can suggest you solutions

Comment: My goal is to provide admin a single login, with which he can login to admin panel as well as frontend. I'm trying to achieve that tweaking into the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/
Customer.php` and `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/
Customer.php`. If i'd be successful I'll share the code with other programmers also, or if anybody already had invented the wheel, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this anser, about logging in as a frontend user (which creates a convenient shortcut to accomplish the same thing, for your client) : [Magento, login as customer from admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413110/magento-login-as-customer-from-admin)

OR

You could use this FREE extension : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-as-customer-9893.html

Description of what it does:

> Features list:
>
> - Admin users can login as customers from "customer view" pages in admin
> - There is an option to allow login as a customer right on the "order view" pages in admin
> - There is an access control option. Admin can assign to a specific role whether role users can login as customers.
> - Does not require to setup customer universal password, because password is less secure.

Or, you could download it, look at the approach used in the code and adapt it :)